# How can i both go over a dictionary and use a counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to save a counter variable while going over a dictionary. In the following code I've specified the place where i need it to be:

```
d = dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4], b=[10, 20, 30])

d = dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4], b=[10, 20, 30])
cnt = 0
for key in d.keys():
    cnt+=1
    print(f'{cnt}) {key}:{d[key]}')
```

my question is: how can i get rid of the `cnt` variable but stil keep track of the line?
Is it possible?

Comment: Looks like you need `enumerate()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use enumerate, and pass `1` as the starting value, you can just do:

```
for count, (key, value) in enumerate(d.items(), 1):
    print(f"{count} {key}:{value}")
```

Also, use `items` since you want to iterate of the key-value pairs.

Finally, if you *did* just want to iterate over the keys, just do:

```
for key in my_dictionary:
    ...
```

No need for `.keys`